# How to trigger a function on user creation with django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to django and I would like to know if it is possible to trigger a function after a user has been created? For user creation I use the django administration interface.

I want to assign a default theme to a user and to do this I have the following class in my models.py file

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
selected_theme = models.TextField(max_length=50, default="Clair")
```

This class allows me to store the theme selected by the user
I would like to use a function that assigns a theme to a user when creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you need to add the following lines to the model.py file in your Profile Class:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
selected_theme = models.TextField(max_length=50, default="Clair")

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```